# Looking for help on VSCode extension

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

I've been through approximately 2/3 of all the vscode extensions but haven't found what I'm looking for yet.

I'm looking for a vscode extension like live server that highlights the portion of the browser you're working on in vscode. For example: if I click on or highlight a p tag it highlights the portion of the browser and puts a highlighted border around the same paragraph in the browser and while I'm typing it automatically updates as I type.

Comment: No ideal one. Please upvote this issue on github https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/12080

Closest one is the edge devtools https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-edgedevtools.vscode-edge-devtools  
but it's far from ideal.

Comment: Use the same setup with Brackets as your editor, or look at the source of Brackets and make a VSC alternative

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you will be able to find something exactly what you are looking for. THe closest you can get, I believe, is [DevTools for Chrome extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=codemooseus.vscode-devtools-for-chrome), which is just devtools put into the editor window, for highlighting DOM elements etc.; and [Debugger for Chrome](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome), for, well, debugging scripts (breakpoints etc., which sadly don't work in the first one; while at the same time the second doesn't deal with DOM at all I think).

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for. a good example of what i'm looking for is from a youtube channel. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B_E6Kh9YkFM&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9i3FXJSUfmsNOx8E7u6UuhG&index=12&t=31s

Comment: Yeah, nothing like this, sadly. There is an ongoing issue for just this feature, but for whatever reason it's not being picked up by the devs: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/12080